# Is there a way to use Sharepoint version history to make a calculated column value?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online, power-automate

I cannot see a way to do this natively, but essentially I would like to tap into the version history for a specific field value to calculate the difference between the current value and the last entered value.

Scenario:
Business user will update a numeric value in a column for each list item once a week to a cumulative amount. (i.e. Sales made to date)

I am currently able to see in the version history what the last entered value was, who entered it, and when it was entered. I want to know if there is a way to access this information in the form of a calculated column to find this difference (i.e. sales made this week). The solution I am thinking is adding another column for "Total Sales Last Week" and have the user manually update that when they update "Total Sales This Week" then have a calculated column to just subtract these values. However, this seems tedious since the information is already in Sharepoint. If there is a way to do this either with a calculated column, PowerAutomate flow or another method please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to capture the Version History using calculated column. REST API is the only option that will be helpful to fetch these details. Considering this, there are two solutions that I can suggest here:

1. **Using REST API**

   - Create an additional column in your list and update it with the data that you will capture from version history using SharePoint REST API. Here, Rest API will be used to fetch the version history and also to update the list item.
   - As a trigger event to execute this code, Either you can setup a button on the page (if using any custom screen) or set this to execute periodically.
2. **Using REST API in Power Automate (Recommended)**

   - Power Automate/MS Flow doesn't provide any direct connector to fetch the version history but you can use the HTTP request connector which will help you to execute the SP rest call to fetch the version history.
   - Once you have version history data from your HTTP request call, you can use that to update the column in your list using the same power automate in next action.
   - This solution will be more useful as you don't need to setup any trigger event as mentioned in the first solution but instead of that you can simply configure this Power Automate to run as and when list item is updated and you will be having immediate result in your list.

You can refer to [this link](https://www.alanps1.io/power-platform/flow/flow-create-sharepoint-list-rest-api-with-power-automate/) to check how to get data from HTTP request using Power automate and you can also refer to [this link](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/257870/how-to-get-version-history-of-item-using-rest) which will help you to understand how to get version history using SharePoint rest API.

I hope this will be useful information for you to achieve your goal.